# How to unwrap 2 different meshes in a way that both meshes will have identical UV map(suitable for normal baking)?

Tags: mesh, uv, workflow

So, I'm making game ready models which require me to model a high poly mesh, then I decimate it's duplicate to create a low poly mesh, and then I import them into an external software where I bake normals, but it only works if the UV maps of the two meshes are identical.

*Now, when I have these 2 different meshes in blender, is there a way that I can use to **make them have the same UV maps?***

*P.S. Lets avoid marking seams* & *Retopology*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unwrap multiple objects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15676/how-to-unwrap-multiple-objects)

Comment: Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68877/how-do-i-uv-unwrap-multiple-objects-to-one-uv-map

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos none of these answer my question, the problem is not in unwrapping multiple objects, it's in matching of the UV maps of these different meshes

Comment: The critical point is that they be the same - and this is possible by creating the low poly first and then creating the high poly from that, but it precludes geometry added that is not accounted for in the original mapping.....

Comment: If I were you, I would start with the low-poly mesh, UV map it, then duplicate the low-poly, SubSurf it, and sculpt it. Then I would bake the high-poly normals from the sculpt back onto the low-poly mesh. I would do this all in Blender, as both Cycles and Blender Render support normal map baking.

Comment: @Mentalist but what if I have a highpoly model already? I used to model the low poly first but now I have to model the highpoly first to make sure it looks the way I want it to.

Comment: @IgorTatarnikov Then you have to do retopo over your high-poly mesh to create the low-poly mesh.

Comment: @mentalist what if I have a crazy sub div on it? Is there no other way??

Comment: A workflow I find works well is: Model a base mesh with good low-poly topo. 2.Duplicate that and sculpt it. 3.Duplicate your base mesh again, SubSurf and Shrinkwrap it to the sculpt, nudging verts and tweaking Shrinkwrap settings if needed. 4. Apply the modifiers. 5. Add a Multires Modifier and at the highest subdivision level (matching your applied shrinkwrap mesh's level) 6.Reshape the Multires. [More info here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38307/retopo-can-we-apply-shrink-wrap-to-multires-subdivisions) Then you have both high and low poly in one mesh!