# UV mapping, some models on one layout?

Tags: texturing, uv

I have problem with UV layout :
I try this 3 UV models place on 1 layout uv :
[image]

This models have the same material, but when i select 3 beams my house i have only one.
I expects this result : 
[image]

How i can do this ?

Comment: Try using a **Texture Atlas** add on: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68877/how-do-i-uv-unwrap-multiple-objects-to-one-uv-map and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15676/how-to-unwrap-multiple-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one object at a time can be UV-unwrapped (except when using an add-on like Texture Atlas). When this is done, the mesh datablock for that object gets a UV Map assigned to it.

If you want to UV map that whole structure together, you can first select and join the multiple mesh objects (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>).

When you do this the mesh pieces will all become one object, and take the name of the object that was selected *last*. This last-select object is called the Active Object, and notice how its selection color is a little bit different from the other selected objects.

You might consider leaving the door as its own separate object, since it may move, or you can have it *all* as one mesh and still animate the door by rigging it. But you haven't mentioned animation so I'm getting ahead of myself. Anyway, the idea is to organize your mesh data into larger, easier to manage objects.