# Texture paint without affecting other object with same texture/material

Tags: modeling, texture-painting

i edit my post maybe will better understand it now :)

Edit: so i create a gun created from many mesh,
so i want to paint lets say CUBE A but result is show in CUBE B,C,etc
i use same material(i named it BLACK METAL) for each mesh

so i want to know how to paint only CUBE A without making new image file or new material

so i dont want to create new material (black steel barrel,black steel gun body,etc) for every mesh i think i'ts unproductive

[image: a]

GIF info:look i select CUBE A then i select CUBE C then B then i try texture paint on CUBE A but it show on CUBE B too then i try again to paint CUBE A then CUBE C and B get painted too

if still not clear sorry not good explainer :(

Comment: You need to change your UV Map, because more than one face is looking at the same location on the texture image. You don't necessarily have to create a new UV unwrap, but you will have to modify it.

Comment: i think you misunderstand here what i mean by part is a mesh object i separate all gun part into many object actually

Comment: you don't exacty help others to understand what you set there, using those really small gifs...

Comment: Objects are different but the texture they use is the same and the UV map layout is made so parts of one object get painted strokes made for other object visible. Join objects, modeify UV map so islands sit separately and separate objects back. One solution without joining with Ctrl+J is using Texture Atlas addon, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68877/how-do-i-uv-unwrap-multiple-objects-to-one-uv-map and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15676/how-to-unwrap-multiple-objects

Answer (score 1):

Select 'Face Selection Masking' from the icon on the view header just to the left of the layer dialogue and that will limit by selection in the Texture Paint mode. You can make use of Vertex Groups here to go back and forth with selections, or you can use the 'L' key to select linked mesh while still in texture paint mode.[image]

edit: If the image area falls under the same as another part, then the shared pixels will show no matter what. Your uv map has to give separate space for all mesh parts similar to Smart Unwrap in order to keep from painting two areas at once in the mapping.

Comment: its still show in another mesh, i edit my post maybe will more clear this time :)